# Where can in install the Firebase App Tester app?

Tags: android, firebase

I am setting up a new phone and already have the App Tester app on my old phone.

On [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/get-set-up-as-a-tester?platform=android) Google recommends installing the app in Step 2, but do not provide a link or any instructions for where one might find that app.

All I want is a link to download the App Tester app. I'm familiar with Firebase etc as I have been using it for months for my team's app development.

**edit:** To clarify, I installed the Tester app on an old device when originally accepting the invitation, [per the instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/get-set-up-as-a-tester?platform=android#download-app-tester). But then I got a new device. As far as I can tell, you have a *single chance* to install the Tester app, which is during accepting the invitation. Since Firebase won't allow repeat email invites, to install the tester app on a new phone I could only think to invite a burner email just to get to the page where Firebase gives you an install link.

I was hoping someone could share the download link for the APK, so I don't need the hacky burner emails to get the app on a device.

Comment: Hey, @Eric can you please check this video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5kUCaNvRus. This is already provided proper guidance so this is really helpful.

Comment: I updated my question. The issue is how to get the app on a new device, after already accepting the invitation with a given email (which is when you're offered to download the Tester APK).

Answer (score 2):

In the invite email for the test release, you will be prompted to install it, so you will need to open the link on the target phone the first time you set it up.

This is what they write in their guide:

> If you haven't already, download the Firebase App Tester app, which
> lets you install and access all your test apps in one place. You can
> download Firebase App Tester from the in-browser prompt that appears
> after you accept the invite.

from https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/get-set-up-as-a-tester?platform=android#download-app-tester

I do agree, it is unclear the app is not in Google Play separately, wasted some time looking for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I installed it the first time I accepted the offer on an old device, but then I got a new phone. I couldn't re-invite that email address, and it seems you can _only_ install the app exactly when you accept the invite, it wasn't clear how to get it on my new phone. Had to invite a burner email just to get that screen to load again....

Comment: Yes, and even then the option to keep it on the device is easy to miss, it's a notification in the lower part of the screen. I didn't realise before now it's a web app and not a native app. Happy to hear you found a way. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and this solution helped me: Reinvite in firebase app. I got email from firebase - clicking on GetStarted button started webview (unfortunately in desktop mode and it was the problem). I had to setup to start it as mobile version. After that prompt to download app finaly appears.

Comment: This is what worked for me. Seems the firebase folks don't have tablets at hand for testing